# How can I tell Firefox to visual highlight focus cursor to make it more visually noticeable?

Tags: gnome, firefox, accessibility

How might I highlight the current focus cursor in Firefox? That is, how do I make the cursor that moves focus when pressing the tab key more visual? Given my current desk situation, my keyboard is comfortably placed but the mouse is becoming troublesome to use.

Using

- gnome-shell
- Ubuntu 15
- Firefox 42